Flycheck: how to run AsciiDoctor with Bundler?
Me use Bundler to manage Ruby gems. For example, my Makefile contain this build command:
build:
    bundle exec asciidoctor \
        --source ./src/ \
        ...

It's nicely works, but Flycheck can't find the asciidoctor executable in the project environment. flycheck-status results:
  asciidoctor (automatically disabled) reset
    - may enable: no
    - executable: Not found

How to configure Flycheck for running asciidoctor with Bundler like this?
bundle exec asciidoctor ...


This question has nothing to do with Emacs, and everything to do with your shell’s PATH variable.

Hello! How to set correct value for PATH? Me is newbye for Ruby and Gems ecosystem.
